# Is there a way to run a function before the optimizer updates the weights?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm going through PyTorch tutorial and just learned about `optimizer.step` and how it makes an update to the network's parameters ([here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_nn/two_layer_net_optim.html)).

Is there a way to create a function that whenever theres a gradient updates **to each learnable parameter (e.g weight)**, will take the weight value and the loss, and multiply that value by some percentage of that, say `90%`?
So if the update should be:
`w1 -= lr * loss_value = 1e-5 * 50`
I want it to go through the function before the update and make it `1e-5 * 50 * 90%`

```
def func(loss_value, percentage):
    return loss_value * percentage #new update should be w1 -= loss_value * percentage
```

Example model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(5, 10)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = torch.relu(x)        
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

net = Model()

opt = optim.Adam(net.parameters())
features = torch.rand((3,1)) 
opt.zero_grad()
out = net(features)
loss = torch.tensor(5) - torch.sum(out)
loss.backward()
# need to have the function change the value of the loss update before the optimizer?
opt.step()
```

Comment: Why not just decrease your learning rate? Or, set a learning rate scheduler that sets it to 90% until you step it once?

Comment: Because I want it to take individual weights into account rather than just 1 function (ie 1 learning rate)

Comment: So for different weights you'll have different percentages?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Say the weight is between 0 and 5, the percentage will be 10%, between 5 and 20, 30%, etc. That's why I need a function rather than 1 value (like a learning rate scheduler/etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this bit of code from https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-modify-the-gradient-manually/7483/2 and edited it slightly:

```
loss.backward()
for p in model.parameters():
    weights = p.data
    scales = def_scales(weights)
    p.grad *= scales  # or whatever other operation
optimizer.step()
```

This goes through every parameter in the model (between the loss.backward() and BEFORE the optimizer step) and adjusts its stored gradient BEFORE backprop is applied.

An example `def_scales` will look something like this (*SUPER* ugly), where vals are the compared parameter values, and scales are the desired loss scaling values:

```
def def_scales(weights,scales=[0.1,0.5,1,1],vals=[0,5,10,float('inf')]):
   out = torch.zeros_like(weights)
   for V,v in enumerate(vals[::-1]): #backwards because we're doing less than
      out[weights<=v] = scales[len(scales)-V-1] #might want to compare to abs
   return out
```

Comment: That looks awesome! I'll check it out in an hour or so. Just to verify I understand, `p.grad *= scales ` will change the weight update value, and when I call `optimizer.step()` it will reduce each weight by their corresponding value? i.e `w1-=p1.grad *= scales1`? Also, I didn't quite understand the `backwards because we're doing less than`. Can you explain that part?

Comment: "Less than" in this context means the "<" symbol. It's hacky, but it goes through the values in vals and compares against them to set the values in out. I've done it this way so every value will be set to 1 (for <= inf), then some will be set to the second, then even fewer will be set to the third, etc...

Comment: And yes, optimizer.step() depends on the grad field of each parameter. See the SGD code [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/cd9b27231b51633e76e28b6a34002ab83b0660fc/torch/optim/sgd.py#L63) for example.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

This is a completely unnecessary step since the whole purpose of the learning rate is to take a small fraction of the gradient and make the update to the weights, so I really don't understand what you are trying to do here. and also, the weights update is not according to the equation you wrote, you need to understand the underlying calculus and the gradient descent algorithm. we take the partial derivative of the cost/loss value w.r.t the weights and then multiply it with a small number (learning rate) and subtract it from the initial weights.
if you are doing classification and want to give more importance to one class than the other then you can use Focal Loss function.

Comment: I wrote `loss_value` to count for the partial derivative of the loss wrt weights. Was hoping that it will make sense, but maybe not. Hence, I believe my equations are correct. I want to take individual weights into account in the function, and that's why I didn't just create 1 learning rate

Comment: there's no  'loss_value ' in your code and 'loss_value" can simply means the value of loss that is calculated from your defined loss functions. partial derivatives are calculated in 'loss.bakward()' . 'loss.backward()' computes dloss/dx for every parameter x which has requires_grad=True. Yes you can access the weights of the models and change them but you are just adding another extra hyperparameter to tune by doing so and it doesn't server any particular purpose.